# Change edittext with equally along left and right when setting width

Tags: android, textview, resize, ontouchlistener

I have following setup. 
 [image]

There is an edittext with controllers on left and right for resizing. 
When user resizes by touching and moving the left controller, I am calculating the distance between moved x-coordinate and the mid-point of right side of edittext.

The idea is that the right side has to remain static, where as on resizing from left, the left bound has to increase of decrease like wise. I am assigning new width and center to edittext on resize from left as follows:

```
ivLeftControl.setPivotX(traversedPoint.x);
                    editTextViewNew.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                    editTextViewNew.setWidth((int) (traversedWidth-ivLeftControl.getWidth()*2));
                    editTextViewNew.setPivotX(centerX - (traversedWidth - originalWidth)/2);
```

But the resize is happening only along the right side of edittext, instead of happening along left side. Even when I dont change the pivot, the resize happens along right side only.

[image]

Any suggestion on how this features could be addressed the best?! Keeping in mind, the entire setup of controllers and edittext is enveloped using a parent layout.

Comment: you need to set updated  `layoutparmas`  in to `EditText` .

Comment: Layoutparams for width only or update the margins as well?! I believe for edittext, width can be simply set using edittext.setWidth(). The above issue also happens with I update the layoutparams and set them to parent relative layout.

Comment: you need to update left right margins and width , by doing some claculation with respect to device parent view width for center position.

Comment: I haven't changed the margin based on change in position of controller. But I have been playing around with changing left and right of edittext (using setLeft and setRight methods) in respect to background parent canvas. Simply doing edittext.setLeft(ChangeInPosition) works, but then it nullifies the idea of resizing as text disappears when size is decreased. 
I am trying your suggestion in the meantime. Will update how it goes.

Comment: see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Solution - `MarginLayoutParams`

you need to create MarginLayoutParams and then set height , width , margins in it and set to your view.

```
MarginLayoutParams layoutParams = (MarginLayoutParams) getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.width = mPixelSize;
layoutParams.height = mPixelSize;
layoutParams.setMargins(mLeftMargin, mTopMargin, 0, 0);
requestLayout();
```